# Tesseract returns nothing for Arabic words/letters

Tags: ocr, tesseract, arabic

I have installed Pytesseract and it's working perfectly on French/English text and also in numbers. But when I try to read any Arabic text/letter it doesn't return anything.

Here is the code I have used:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('maroc.jpg'), lang='ara'))
```

Here is the letter I'm trying to read `د`:

[image: د]

If someone was able to read it using another method please help, thanks!

Comment: How about --psm 10 (single character) option? And are these printed characters? Your example looks handwritten.

Comment: It worked with --psm 10 thank you very much. Do you know the equivalent of this argument in the python `pytesseract` package?

Comment: Sorry, I only use tesseract command line. You might edit your question to ask this.

Comment: It's fine I found the argument config that allows this.

Answer (score 5):

Code :

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string 
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr('test.png', lang='ara', extension='hocr'))
```

Take new Arabic tessdata from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/master/ara.traineddata):

Comment: What if we want to extract both english and arabic words. I have image with both english and arabic words but using above technique I am able to extract only arabic words.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to recognise arabic words download the arabic trained model from the link below then save it in the location  according to your Tesseract folder

```
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
```

[arabic_tesseract_trained](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/ara.traineddata)

Answer (score 0):

for raspberry pi 4 just download module from [Eliyaz KL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952817/16916634) answer and put in this path
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/
i don't know which operating system use i answerd in my case